# Add extra tick of the beginning of a d3 time axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been working on an x-axis that will format the ticks on the axis according to an interval variable set elsewhere. which is a string ('decade','lustrum','years', days' etc). I have it working it generally does the job. Below is an example of a date range between 17/8/19198 to 24/08/2017 with a lustrum (five years) interval. There is a secondary (minor) axis with no tick labels that also changes according to the interval/ I've also added some formatting to our house style.
Example

[image]

The problem I'm having is that I'd like to add an extra tick on the beginning of the major axis so that it matches out house style as we always mark the initial date. I've used .nice() but this adds a tick to the end also, it also defaults to the next rounded increment on the axis so if the chart started in 2009 and I had an interval of decade then the .nice would force the chart back to the year 2000 which is no good

What I would like to achieve is this
[image]his:

I thought that it would be as easy as accesing the axis tick array and unshifting the domain()[0] value into the zero position. But that doesn't seem to work. I don't actually seem to accessing the ticks when I asign them to the test variable. What i get back is a date scale every two years.

Any pointers would be appreciated, thanks

This is the code I have:

```
function xaxisDate() {
    let mindate = new Date(1970, 1, 1);
    let maxdate = new Date(2017, 6, 1);
    let scale = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain([mindate, maxdate])
        .range([0, 220]);
    let frameName;
    let interval = 'lustrum';
    let minorAxis = true;
    let tickSize = 10;
    let minorTickSize = 5;
    let fullYear = false;
    let align = 'bottom';
    let xLabel;
    let xLabelMinor;

    function axis(parent) {
        //scale.nice(getTicks(interval))
        function getAxis(alignment) {
            return {
                top: d3.axisTop(),
                bottom: d3.axisBottom(),
            }[alignment];
        }

        const xAxis = getAxis(align)
            .tickSize(tickSize)
            .ticks(getTicks(interval))
            .tickFormat(tickFormat(interval))
            .scale(scale)

        test = scale.ticks()
        console.log('before',test);

        // console.log('domain',scale.domain()[0])
        // scale.ticks().unshift(scale.domain()[0]);
        // console.log('after',scale.ticks())
        // xAxis.tickValues()

        const xMinor = d3.axisBottom()
            .tickSize(minorTickSize)
            .ticks(getTicksMinor(interval))
            .tickFormat('')
            .scale(scale);

        xLabel = parent.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'axis xAxis axis baseline')
            .call(xAxis);

        if (minorAxis) {
            xLabelMinor = parent.append('g')
                .attr('class', (d) => {
                    const plotHeight = d3.select('.chart-plot').node().getBBox().height;
                    if (plotHeight === tickSize) {
                        return 'axis xAxis';
                    }
                    return 'axis xAxis axis baseline';
                })
                .call(xMinor);
        }

        if (frameName) {
            xLabel.selectAll('.axis.xAxis text')
            .attr('id', frameName + 'xLabel');
            xLabel.selectAll('.axis.xAxis line')
            .attr('id', frameName + 'xTick');
            if (minorAxis) {
                xLabelMinor.selectAll('.axis.xAxis line')
                .attr('id', frameName + 'xTick');
            }
        }

        xLabel.selectAll('.domain').remove();
    }

    function getTicks(interval) {
        console.log('interval',interval)
        return {
            'century' : d3.timeYear.every(100),
            'jubilee': d3.timeYear.every(50),
            'decade': d3.timeYear.every(10),
            'lustrum': d3.timeYear.every(5),
            'years': d3.timeYear.every(1),
            'quarters': d3.timeMonth.every(3),
            'months': d3.timeMonth.every(1),
            'weeks': d3.timeWeek.every(1),
            'days': d3.timeDay.every(1),
            'hours': d3.timeHour.every(1)
        }[interval];
    }
    function getTicksMinor(interval) {
        const test = d3.timeYear.every(1);
        console.log('test', test)
        return {
            'century': d3.timeYear.every(10),
            'jubilee': d3.timeYear.every(10),
            'decade': d3.timeYear.every(1),
            'lustrum': d3.timeYear.every(1),
            'years': d3.timeMonth.every(1),
            'quarters': d3.timeMonth.every(1),
            'months': d3.timeDay.every(1),
            'weeks': d3.timeDay.every(1),
            'days': d3.timeHour.every(1),
            'hours': d3.timeMinute.every(1)
        }[interval];
    }

    function tickFormat(interval) {
        let formatFullYear = d3.timeFormat('%Y'),
        formatYear = d3.timeFormat('%y'),
        formatMonth = d3.timeFormat('%b'),
        formatWeek = d3.timeFormat('%W'),
        formatDay = d3.timeFormat('%d'),
        formatHour = d3.timeFormat('%H:%M');
        return {
            'century': d3.timeFormat('%Y'),
            'jubilee': function(d, i) {
                const format = checkCentury(d, i);
                return format;
            },
            'decade': function(d, i) {
                const format = checkCentury(d, i);
                return format;
            },
            'lustrum':function(d, i) {
                const format = checkCentury(d, i);
                return format;
            },
            'years': function(d, i) {
                const format = checkCentury(d, i);
                return format;
            },
            'quarters':function(d, i) {
                const format = getQuarters(d, i);
                return format;
            },
            'months': function(d, i) {
                const format = checkMonth(d, i);
                return format;
            },
            'weeks':function(d, i) {
                const format = getWeek(d, i);
                return format;
            },
            'days':function(d, i) {
                const format = getDays(d, i);
                return format;
            },
            'hours': function(d, i) {
                const format = getHours(d, i);
                return format;
            },
        }[interval];

        function getHours(d, i) {
            if (d.getHours() === 1 || i === 0) {
                return formatHour(d) + ' ' + formatDay(d);
            }
            return formatHour(d);
        }

        function getDays(d, i) {
            if (d.getDate() === 1 || i === 0) {
                return formatDay(d) + ' ' + formatMonth(d);
            }
            return formatDay(d);
        }

        function getWeek(d, i) {
            if (d.getDate() < 9) {
                return formatWeek(d) + ' ' + formatMonth(d);
            }
            return formatWeek(d);
        }

        function getQuarters(d, i) {
            if (d.getMonth() < 3 && i < 4) {
                return 'Q1 ' + formatFullYear(d);
            }
            if (d.getMonth() < 3) {
                return 'Q1';
            }
            if (d.getMonth() >= 3 && d.getMonth() < 6) {
                return 'Q2';
            }
            if (d.getMonth() >= 6 && d.getMonth() < 9) {
                return 'Q3';
            }
            if (d.getMonth() >= 9 && d.getMonth() < 12) {
                return 'Q4';
            }
        }

        function checkMonth(d, i) {
            if (d.getMonth() === 0 || i === 0) {
                const newYear = d3.timeFormat('%b %Y');
                return newYear(d);
            }
            return formatMonth(d);
        }

        function checkCentury(d, i) {
            if (fullYear || (+formatFullYear(d) % 100 === 0) || (i === 0)) {
                return formatFullYear(d);
            }
            return formatYear(d);
        }
    }
    axis.align = (d) => {
        align = d;
        return axis;
    };
    axis.frameName = (d) => {
        if (d === undefined) return frameName;
        frameName = d;
        return axis;
    };
    axis.scale = (d) => {
        scale = d;
        return axis;
    };
    axis.domain = (d) => {
        scale.domain(d);
        return axis;
    };
    axis.range = (d) => {
        scale.range(d);
        return axis;
    };

    axis.fullYear = (d) => {
        if (d === undefined) return fullYear;
        fullYear = d;
        return axis;
    };
    axis.interval = (d) => {
        interval = d;
        return axis;
    };
    axis.tickSize = (d) => {
        if (!d) return tickSize;
        tickSize = d;
        return axis;
    };
    axis.minorTickSize = (d) => {
        if (!d) return minorTickSize;
        minorTickSize = d;
        return axis;
    };
    axis.minorAxis = (d) => {
        if (d === undefined) return minorAxis;
        minorAxis = d;
        return axis;
    };
    axis.xLabel = (d) => {
        if (d === undefined) return xLabel;
        xLabel = d;
        return axis;
    };
    axis.xLabelMinor = (d) => {
        if (d === undefined) return xLabelMinor;
        xLabelMinor = d;
        return axis;
    };
    return axis;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in tickValues. You need to return the values of the tick array then and as I thought unshifet the domain[0] value into it. After you set up the xAxis you need to insert the following:

```
 let newTicks = scale.ticks(getTicks(interval))
        newTicks.unshift(scale.domain()[0]);
        xAxis.tickValues(newTicks)
```